# "Required" DataAnnotation throws unHandled exception

Tags: silverlight, validation, data-annotations

I'm trying to use DataAnnotations in Silverlight 4 to validate user inputs.

In this example, everything goes as expected:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtName" Margin="15,0,0,0" MinWidth="200" Height="Auto" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True, NotifyOnValidationError=True}"/>
```

With this ViewModel code:

```
#region Name
private string name;

[Display(Name="Pet Name", Description="Here goes the pet's name")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Name must be 3 - 50 characters", MinimumLength=3)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Name" });
                
                this.name= value;

                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                this.AceptarCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

The problem comes when I try to add a "Required" DataAnnotation:

## region Name

```
private string name;

[Display(Name="Pet Name", Description="Here goes the pet's name")]
[Required(ErrorMessage="You must write a name")]
[StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Name must be 3 - 50 characters", MinimumLength=3)]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return name;
            }
            set
            {
                Validator.ValidateProperty(value, new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "Name" });
                
                this.name= value;

                this.RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                this.AceptarCommand.OnCanExecuteChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

When ValidateProperty executes, it throws an unhandled exception when the page loads the first time (it has no default value).

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the problem.

This was caused because I was initializing textbox binded value (Name) in DataContext constructor so it threw the exception before everything was constructed (maybe visualtree...).

So you have to do this AFTER construction.